How to make an Array of Texts read from a String
I'm trying to create a quiz game, exactly like how Jeopardy works. Right now, I'm attempting to make text objects from the top row each display a different item from a String, which lists all the categories, which if I can do that, it would help give an idea with the next step, getting text from a prefab to show a set question and answer based on which button the player chooses.
Tl Dr: Row (Parent Object) > Cells (Child Object), Text as either Child Object of Cells/direct child of Row
Text Object 1 - 6
--------------->
String Item 1 - 6
Text 1 reads Item/Category 1, Text 2 reads Item/Category 2, etc
So far as practice, I've been able to make individual panels of the top row show a single number.
public class CategoryRow : MonoBehaviour {

    public ClueCell[] cells { get; private set; }

        public int Size => cells.Length;

        public TextMeshProUGUI category_;

        public Text Categories;

    public void Awake() {
        cells = GetComponentsInChildren<ClueCell>();
    }

    public void Start() {
        int number = 1;
        category_.text = "Category " + number.ToString();

        Categories.text = "Category " + number.ToString();
    }
}

But if I try to do something like this:
public class CategoryRow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ClueCell[] cells { get; private set; }
    public int Size => cells.Length;

    public TextMeshProUGUI category_;
    public Text Categories;

    public int[] CategoryNum = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public void Awake()
    {
        cells = GetComponentsInChildren<ClueCell>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //int number = 1;
        for(int x = 1; x < cells.Length; x++)
        {
            category_.text = "Category " + CategoryNum[x].ToString();
            Categories.text = "Category " + CategoryNum[x].ToString();
        }
    }
}

It stops working. At this point, my brain is completely fried trying to look at other related posts and guides, and I feel like I'm missing something and getting lines of code, including what I've posted here, mixed up from so many different attempts. If there's a way to do this without having to go, Text 1 = "", Text 2 = "", etc, I would very much like to know.

Welcome new user. Just read them from a text file.  Search on "read test from file in Unity" or ask another question!
